# Focusing control doesn't work

Tags: wpf, command, focus

I have a Window filled with a TreeView and other controls. After a user has selected an item of the TreeView, I want to trigger a command when the Enter key is pressed and change the focus to the TreeView afterwards, so that the selection can be seen.

The command call works with this code:

```
<Window ...>
    ...
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" Key="Enter"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    ...
    <TreeView x:Name="tv" ...>
        ...
    </TreeView>
</Window>
```

But I don't know how to change the focus to the TreeView after the Command was executed. How do I do that in XAML or in Codebehind? XAML answers are preferred.

This is what I tried:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=ChangeCategoryCommand}" Key="Enter" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tv}"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

But the selection in the TreeView is not visible after pressing Enter, so I am obviously doing something wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a code-behind solution:

```
<Window 
PreviewKeyUp="OnPreviewKeyUp">
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<TreeView x:Name="tv" />
```

and the code-behind:

```
private void OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            this.tv.Focus();
        }
    }
```

FYI: The selected item of a treeview is readonly, so not really usable with a binding.